# Styling based on state instead of props

Tags: styled-components

I want to style a component based on it's state (instead of props), which changes with clicking.

However, I don't see any way to do this without pulling state up into a wrapper and passing the down the state to props. Which seems needless. Is there a way to access state with styled-components?

I would like to do something like this:

```
const styledDiv = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(state) => state.x};
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution recommended by the developers of the library is to pull the state up. I have to agree.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is pass in your state into the styled-component as a prop. Like so...

JS

```
return (
  <div>
    <StyledDiv customPropName={this.state.x}>example text</StyledDiv>
  </div>
);
```

Styled-Component

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.x};
`
```